# How to pass URL parameters through templateUrl in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to learn AngulareJS got stuck with this.

This is the code :

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/',
{       
    templateUrl: '/sort',
    controller : 'tasksController'      
})  
.when('/expression/:expressionId/type/:typeId',
{   
    templateUrl: '/sort/'+:expressionId +'/'+ :typeId,
    controller : 'tasksController'  
})});
```

This is obviously wrong.

Can any one please tell me what is the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us why it is wrong.  What is the behavior you are getting?

Comment: The way you're trying to approach it is not possible with Angular's "native" router. It is, however, possible with [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#angularui-router-). If you wanted to stick with ngRouter, you could use a combination of $routeParams (populated within a controller), and ngInclude within your main view.

Comment: I figured it out.Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks guys,this is what I wanted

```
.when('/expression/:expressionId/type/:typeId', {

templateUrl: function(params) {
    return '/sort/' + params.expressionId +'/'+ params.typeId ;
},
controller: 'tasksController'
});
```

Comment: I know it is a bit late to comment here, but, can you explain where are you passing 'params', where params get its value from?! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for $routeparams
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams.

you can do something like below:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: '/sort',
        controller : 'tasksController'
    })
    .when('/expression/:expressionId/type/:typeId', {
        templateUrl: '/sort',
        controller : 'tasksController'
    })
});

app.controller('tasksController', ['$scope', '$routeparams', function($scope, $routeparams) {
    var expressionId = $routeparams.expressionId
        , typeId = $routeparams.typeId;
}]);
```

Comment: I figured it out.Thank you for your response.