# How can I pass the id into the template url

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I need to pass the id into the template url using routeProvider. Because one of my views requires that id.

```
.when(phoneView/:phoneId ,/*pass this id to this ->*/
templateUrl: "<?php echo site_url('phone/view/*phoneId should be here*')?>)"
```

How can I do this? I need help.

Comment: Use double quote there <?php echo site_url("phone/view/*phoneId")?>);

Comment: Anand Pandey thanks a bunch. It worked. I had not paid attention to that. Thanks again.

Comment: Please accep tmy answer if you like :)

Comment: I also came across another detailed answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713653/how-to-pass-url-parameters-through-templateurl-in-angularjs/23715846#23715846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quote on this line.

```
 <?php echo site_url("phone/view/*phoneId")?>);
```